# Can one use likelihood ratio test to determine if a random effect is significantly non-zero?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I've constructed a mixed effect model in R to test for a fixed effect of condition and fit random slopes to each subject, using the unique task solution for each subject. It looks like this:

```
mdl <- lmer(dv ~ condition + (solution|subject), data = E1_data, 
REML = FALSE)
```

I know that to test whether the fixed effect is significant, I would test against a null model to obtain a likelihood ratio, like this:

```
mdl.null <- lmer(dv ~ (solution|subject), data = E1_data, 
REML = FALSE)

anova(mdl.null, mdl)
```

**How would I test whether the** **distribution of random slopes**, fitted to each subject, **is significantly different from zero**? Could I test a null random slopes model against my full model, as shown below?

```
mdl.nullSlope <- lmer(dv ~ condition + (1|subject), data = E1_data, 
REML = FALSE)

anova(mdl.nullSlope, mdl)
```

Comment: Why do you have `(solution|subject)` term but don't have fixed effect of `solution`? This is weird. This would mean that you *assume* that the average effect of `solution` is exactly zero.

Comment: The effect of solution per subject does average to 0 (intentional).